# What is the difference between web services and RPC?

Tags: web-services, rpc

Web services are now preferred over Remote Procedure Calls.

What is main difference between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between remote procedure call and web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028899/what-is-the-difference-between-remote-procedure-call-and-web-service)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Currently most Web services architectures adopt RPC as their 
>   architectural style. But because of the complexity of RPC, there are 
>   bottlenecks of RPC-style Web services in Web-scale applications. REST 
>   not only can make full use of Web features, but also has the advantage
>   of simplicity. So REST becomes a new alternative to RPC for Web 
>   services architecture. In this paper, at first the brief introductions
>   of RPC and REST are provided. Then two kinds of architectural styles 
>   are analyzed and compared from the perspectives of scalability, 
>   coupling, and security. In the end the development trend of Web 
>   services architecture is prospected.

Copied from: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5339611

> Web Service a higher level representation of RPC. A web service is a
>   specific implementation of RPC. At its lowest level, all a web service
>   is, is connecting to a socket, using the HTTP protocol to negotiate
>   sending a payload that is executed in a remote space (it may even be
>   on the same computer, for all the consumer knows). All those
>   abstractions are at its core RPC.

Copied from: [What is the difference between remote procedure call and web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028899/what-is-the-difference-between-remote-procedure-call-and-web-service)

> Further attributes of a Web Service in addition to what Wayne wrote:
>   allows a platform independent way of a RPC, is discoverable and self
>   describing (compare that with a Win32 RPC)

http://savas.me/2005/07/web-services-are-rpc/

Comment: What's the use of downvoting without telling the author what he can do to improve the answer?